# Autofac's named method

Tags: autofac

I'd like to identify some types using a service name.

I need exactly what is showen in [this example](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/NewInV2#Convention-Based_%28Data-Driven%29_Registration)

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(controllers)
.Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IController))
.Named(t => "controller-" + t.Name.ToLower());
```

But the method `named` has no overload which takes one argument of type string(only the generic one does). 
The method takes a second argument of type type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a mistake in the documentation and you should use either

```
Named<IController>(t => "controller-" + t.Name.ToLower())
```

or

```
Named(t => "controller-" + t.Name.ToLower(), typeof(IController))
```